# c++ FILE struct parameters meaning

Tags: c++, file, curl, io

now working with `curl` and have callback function to store result into file:

```
size_t WriteData(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
```

Also I need to count `MD5` of recieved file. But reading downloaded file again to count `MD5` is bad idea so I want to get a buffer that I store into file use it as a partitial `MD5` calculation formula parameter.

As I understand `FILE` struct has a member called `_base` where all data to be written into file are kept, however I need to know its size. As I thought size should be `nmemb` but I did small test:

```
size_t WriteData(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    for (int i = 0; i < nmemb; ++i)
        std::cout << stream->_base[i];
    return written;
}
```

After I append this function to print data into screen I saw, that it prints lots of garbage, so my question, how to get data buffer size?

Comment: FILE is an opaque type and you should not presume of what it contains.

Comment: Please decide if you're programming in C or in C++, mixing them is very confusing since "the right answer" is rarely the same for both languages.

Comment: @unwind I'm programming with C++ but this is a C type file writer, I'm using it because it is faster then streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: This is an answer to the question I believe should have been asked, rather than the question actually asked. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Instead of messing with the internals of the C library, which is never a good idea, you should just provide libcurl with your own userdata. You can set the userdata with the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` option when you initialize the transfer.

It's precisely for this sort of application that libcurl provides you with the possibility to set your own userdata, instead of just passing a FILE*.

Roughly speaking, the code would look something like this:

```
// All error checking has been omitted; don't use this code as is.

// This is the userdata you'll be using
typedef struct FileWithMD5 {
  FILE*   file;
  MD5_CTX md5_ctx;
} FileWIthMD5;

// The transfer function we'll be using
size_t write_with_md5(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t  nmemb,
                      void *userdata);

// This function is called before the transfer is started.
// The return value needs to be passed to the finalize function.
FileWithMD5* initialize_transfer(CURL *handle, const char* filename) {
  // Allocate a userdata
  FileWithMD5* userdata = malloc(sizeof(*userdata));
  userdata->file = fopen(filename, "w");
  MD5Init(&userdata->md5_ctx);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURL_WRITEDATA, userdata);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURL_WRITEFUNCTION, write_with_md5);
  return userdata;
}

// This function is called after the transfer is finished.
void finalize_transfer_and_extract_md5(CURL *handle,
                                       FileWithMD5* userdata,
                                       u_int8_t md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]) {
  // Close the file, extract the MD5, and get rid of the userdata
  close(userdata->file);
  MD5Final(md5, &userdata->md5_ctx);
  free(userdata);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURL_WRITEDATA, 0);
}

// Callback function
size_t write_with_md5(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t  nmemb,
                      void *vuserdata) {
  FileWithMD5* userdata = vuserdata;
  // Write the data and update the MD5
  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, userdata->file);
  MD5Update(&userdata->md5_ctx, (const u_int8_t*)ptr, written);
  return written;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `FILE` are opaque, and an implementation which
only provided a forward reference for it would be conforming.
And it would be a rare implementation which kept everything in
the buffer.  What you want to do is calculate your `MD5` on the
buffer you pass into `fwrite`.

As for your second example:

```
std::cout << std::string( static_cast<char const*>( ptr ), size * nmemb );
```

But this will only work if you're actually writing text data.